# Does WaitForExit actually wait for an external program to finish?

Tags: c#

I'm writing an application where there are two calls to external programs, RichCopy and 7zip.  The idea is to use RichCopy to move files and 7zip to archive and encrypt the files once RichCopy finishes.  The problem I'm having is that the application isn't waiting for RichCopy to finish moving files before 7zip tries to archive them despite the fact that I'm using WaitForExit.  Code is below:

```
file_copy(groupNumberINT, groupNumber, extFolderPath, scanFolderPath);
encrypt_data(groupNumber, outputFolder);

    private void file_copy(int groupNumberINT, string groupNumber, string externalFolder, string scansFolder)
    {
        if (groupNumberINT < 370)
        {
            string sourceFolder = "D:\\Test\\Production\\CMSFILE001-Copy\\" + groupNumber;

            ProcessStartInfo f001 = new ProcessStartInfo();
            f001.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Rich Tools\\RichCopy 4.0\\RichCopy.exe"; //Edit in prod
            f001.Arguments = sourceFolder + " " + externalFolder;
            f001.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

            Process f1 = Process.Start(f001);
            f1.WaitForExit();
        }
    }

    private void encrypt_data(string groupNumber, string outputDirectory)
    {
        // Create 7zip encrypted archive
        string archiveName = groupNumber + @".7z";
        string archiveFolder = @"D:\Test\" + groupNumber;
        string outputFile = tbGroupNumber.Text + ".7z";

        ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
        p.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7za.exe";
        p.Arguments = "a -mx -mhe -pPassword fileout.7z folder";
        p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

        Process x = Process.Start(p);
        x.WaitForExit();
    }
```

So RichCopy kicks off, but immediately after I see the splash screen for RichCopy 7zip starts archiving and encrypting an empty folder.  Is there something I'm missing or is the WaitForExit() method supposed to wait until the process finishes before moving on to the next line of code?

Comment: According to the docs, it should wait. Does `file_copy` work correctly, if you do not call `encrypt_data`? Do your folder names contain whitespace?

Comment: Try   f001.FileName = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Rich Tools\\RichCopy 4.0\\RichCopy.exe\""; //Edit in prod

Comment: @Henrik - file_copy is working correctly.  All the files I want to move are getting moved.

Comment: @artm - I tried your edit, but unfortunately I got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for exit does wait for an external process to finish.

My guess is that the first richcopy executable you started probably starts another process which then does the real copying work.

A working example of Wait for exit:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public class MainApp
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        string textFile = @"c:\workspace\1.txt";
        openNotepad(textFile);
        openNotepad(textFile);    
    }

    private static void openNotepad(string textfile)
    {         
         ProcessStartInfo f001 = new ProcessStartInfo();
         f001.FileName = "notepad.exe";
         f001.Arguments = textfile;
         f001.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
         Process f1 = Process.Start(f001);
         f1.WaitForExit();    
     }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll do some digging into RichCopy to see what's going on there.  I debated using a Wait command, but because the directories to be copied are variable in size I don't think I can safely choose a time for the program to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. instead of void file_copy(), return Process. The process you return is f1.
2. in encrypt_data, add a Process argument and set this to the process you return from file_copy.
3. then, in encrypt_data, wait for the process to finish before you start the zip process.

What I think is happening is that the WaitForExit in file_copy for some reason is non-blocking. Either it's optimized away because there's nothing behind it, or it does wait, but the next line of the calling function is started anyway.

Another possibility is that your file_copy starts RichCopy with malformed arguments, which causes it to exit early (either because it doesn't do anything, or because it returns an error). Try running file_copy separately to see if it works properly and does what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Nate - I'll give these suggestions a try.  I did try to isolate the file copy part of the program and that is working as expected.  When I run the program a second time, 7zip actually sees  the previously moved files from the first run and archives/encrypts them as expected as well but I just can't seem to get it to wait for RichCopy to finish.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this question in future, what I ended up doing was wrapping a while loop around a check to see if the process "RichCopy64" was still running.  If it was still running I told it to wait for 10 seconds then try again.

Thanks to all who responded - when I get enough rep I'll be sure to upvote your answers.